# APM doesn't work behind a corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, atom-editor

The Error I get when I run (sudo) apm install minimap(or any other package):

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.35 | linux | x64
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.21.0/node-v0.21.0.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! install error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:168:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1593:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "install" "--target=0.21.0" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell" "--arch=x64" "--ensure" "--proxy=http://172.31.1.4:8080/"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/anmol/.atom
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Have you tried updating node to the latest version? You're still on `0.10.35` where the latest (at the time of writing) is `0.12.0`. Some node-based tools are highly sensitive to the version of node.

Comment: how about this? https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/322#issuecomment-96430856

Comment: looks like the issue has been fixed with the new release of `request` node module (version `2.66.0`), see [this comment on github](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/322#issuecomment-157685135) for a workaround

Answer (score 6):

you can set proxy for Atom by typing in your terminal:

```
$ apm config set proxy "http://user:pass@host:port"
$ apm config set https_proxy "http://user:pass@host:port"
```

After that you can open Atom and you see quick result ;)

Answer (score 2):

Before running the command use:
export ATOM_NODE_URL=http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist

Comment: The link returns access denied. Can you post it somewhere where I ahve the permission to view the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `apm install [INSERT PACKAGE NAME]`. You must run `apm install .` as per the documentation: https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md

Also, I am not sure if you can download from `https://atom.io/download/atom-shell` behind an `http` proxy.

Comment: I am behind a corporate `HTTP Proxy`, so I was hoping for a workaround. I can still download packages manually, and then build them from source, but a more automated approach would be the preferred solution. Thanks for the input anyways.

Comment: It may not be recommended, but you sure can run apm command to install packages as I stated above, that is if you don't have ! screwing up your proxy settings.

Comment: You can, but then your npm installs and apm installs will have conflicts; as stated, *not recommended*.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your proxy settings using the `apm` CLI tool.

Use:

```
apm config set http-proxy https://userid:pwd@host:port
```

or the following one if no uid and password required:

```
apm config set http-proxy https://host:port
```

To see the configured value use following command:

```
use apm config get http-proxy
```

If you have a `!` (bang) symbol in your settings you're out of luck using `apm config`. There is an issue with parsing `!`.

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for me behind a corporate proxy:
Win7 / apm version 2.4.3 / Atom 1.40.1 x64

=> open or create the file C:\Users\.atom\.apmrc

=> add

```
http-proxy="http://user:pwd@proxy:port"<br>
https-proxy="http://user:pwd@proxy:port"<br>
strict-ssl=false<br>
```

=> from command line, run

```
apm install your-package --verbose
```

=> restart Atom and enjoy